# Ember bind-attr not updating

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a view with the following:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    isSet: false,
    layoutName: 'myview',
    click: function() {
        this.set('isSet', !this.get('isSet'));
    }
};
```

And the template for it:

```
<i {{bind-attr class=":fa isSet:fa-check"}}></i> Toggle
```

The `click` event is working fine, and updates `isSet` (I can see that in ember inspector), but the bound class does not get added.  Is there something wrong in my logic?

Comment: You might want to use `toggleProperty` here.

Comment: As a debugging technique, you could put something like `Value of isSet is {{isSet}}!` in your template to check the value. That might have tipped you off that the value was not getting toggled, and led you to the conclusion that you needed to do `view.isSet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `view.isSet` instead of `isSet` in your template.

```
<i {{bind-attr class=":fa view.isSet:fa-check"}}></i> Toggle
```

Comment: I've got caught by this before, I should have learnt by now... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, not to the OP's problem but to one with a similar title.

When using `bind-attr` to bind property changes and element class, it is important to include also static class mapping inside the `bind-attr` helper and not in a separate, static, class attribute.

This will not always work:

```
<div class="round" {{bind-attr class="highlighted:hl"}}>Inner text</div>
```

The correct way is:

```
<div {{bind-attr class=":round highlighted:hl"}}>Inner text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using above ember 1.11

then use the below tag

Reference :

http://www.hutchinson.io/bind-attr-is-dead/